# How to update SQL column with a CTE based on multiple cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to update the `ActivityCode` column like this:

- if the third sequence of numbers ( by splitting it with `.` as separator ) is between 1 and 24, then add the sequence `02` before it. Example 1st row should be: `110.153.02.11`
- if the third sequence of numbers ( by splitting it with `.` as separator ) is between 25 and 49, then add the sequence `01` before it, but for the last sequence start the count from 1. Example 4th row should be: `110.153.01.01`

More examples:

`110.153.26` --> `110.153.01.02`

`110.153.27` --> `110.153.01.03`

I tried something like this so far, but have zero idea how to continue:

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT WorkActivityTypeId,
                ActivityCode,
                CASE
                  WHEN LEFT(SUBSTRING([ActivityCode],CHARINDEX('.', [ActivityCode])+1, LEN([ActivityCode]) - CHARINDEX('.', [ActivityCode]) ),3) <> '000'
                  THEN  
                    ???
                  ELSE ActivityCode
                END NewActivityCode
         FROM   [VanBerloERP_Acc].[dbo].[WorkActivityTypesTest])
UPDATE cte
SET    ActivityCode = NewActivityCode;
```

Comment: Could you tag the DBMS you are using?

Comment: done, MS SQL Server.

Comment: is the length of the last sequense always 2 (digits) and are the first 2 always 3 and 3 long?

Comment: yes. always 2 digits long, and the first ones always 3 and 3.

Comment: I think you mean the 4th row should be `110.119.01.01`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases when the right 2 digits are 1 through 24, you just need to stuff '.02' into the string.

For cases when the right 2 digits are 25 through 49, you need to add '.01' to the first pair, and then subtract 24 from the last number and re-append it. This involves a bit of converting back and forth and it looks messy the way I did it. Should work though.

I've assumed that the first 2 numbers are always 3 digits and the last two numbers are always 2 digits. If that isn't the case, then this gets messier.

Finally, as a precaution, if the number isn't expected, it just writes the original number back. This could also be avoided by a judicious `WHERE` clause.

This may not be the best way, but it should work.

```
UPDATE
        [VanBerloERP_Acc].[dbo].[WorkActivityTypesTest]
   SET
        ActivityCode =
            CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE( SUBSTRING( ActivityCode, 9, 2 ) AS INT )
                      BETWEEN 1 AND 24
                 THEN STUFF( ActivityCode, 8, 0, '.02' )
                 WHEN TRY_PARSE( SUBSTRING( ActivityCode, 9, 2 ) AS INT )
                      BETWEEN 25 AND 49
                 THEN CONCAT(
                              SUBSTRING( ActivityCode, 1, 7 )
                             ,'.01.'
                             ,RIGHT(
                                     CONCAT(
                                             '00'
                                            ,LTRIM(
                                                    STR( 
                                                         TRY_PARSE( RIGHT( ActivityCode, 2 ) AS INT ) - 24
                                                        ,2
                                                        ,0
                                                       )
                                                  )
                                           )
                                    ,2
                                   )
                            )
                 ELSE ActivityCode
            END
;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this answer is bad form, please direct me to the applicable StackOverflow rule and I'll take this answer down.

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see how this would look with a `MERGE` instead of an update. It doesn't use the OP's table, but the code below runs and produces correct results for the sample set.

It is clearly *not* the most efficient or even a recommended way to solve this problem, but it was a fun exercise.

Here's the `MERGE` solution I came up with:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dottedSet TABLE ( ValueCode VARCHAR(25) );
    
    INSERT
      INTO
            @dottedSet
    VALUES
            ('110.153.11')
           ,('110.117.09')
           ,('110.153.05')
           ,('110.119.25')
           ,('110.153.18')
           ,('110.113.13')
           ,('110.150.12')
           ,('110.152.22')
           ,('110.153.20')
    ;

     MERGE
      INTO
            @dottedSet DS
     USING
            (
              SELECT
                      SPLIT.ValueCode
                     ,CONCAT(
                              SPLIT.PREFIX
                             ,SPLIT.INFIX
                             ,REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( CONCAT( '00', SPLIT.SUFFIX ) ), 1, 2 ) )
                            )                                                                       AS 'NEW_CODE'
            
                FROM
                      (
                        SELECT
                                DS2.ValueCode
                               ,SUBSTRING( DS2.ValueCode, 1, 8 )                                    AS 'PREFIX'
                               ,CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE( SUBSTRING( DS2.ValueCode, 9, 2 ) AS INT ) 
                                          BETWEEN 1 AND 24
                                     THEN '02.'
                                     WHEN TRY_PARSE( SUBSTRING( DS2.ValueCode, 9, 2 ) AS INT ) 
                                          BETWEEN 25 AND 49
                                     THEN '01.'
                                     ELSE ''
                                END                                                                 AS 'INFIX'
                               ,CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE( SUBSTRING( DS2.ValueCode, 9, 2 ) AS INT ) 
                                          BETWEEN 25 AND 49
                                     THEN LTRIM( STR( TRY_PARSE( SUBSTRING( DS2.ValueCode, 9, 2 ) AS INT ) - 24, 2, 0 ) )
                                     ELSE LTRIM( STR( TRY_PARSE( SUBSTRING( DS2.ValueCode, 9, 2 ) AS INT ), 2, 0 ) )
                                END                                                                 AS 'SUFFIX'
                          FROM
                                @dottedSet DS2
                       )  SPLIT
            ) NEW_DS
        ON  DS.ValueCode = NEW_DS.ValueCode
      WHEN  MATCHED
      THEN  UPDATE
               SET
                    DS.ValueCode = NEW_DS.NEW_CODE
    OUTPUT
            DELETED.ValueCode   AS 'OLD_VALUE_CODE'
           ,INSERTED.ValueCode  AS 'NEW_VALUE_CODE'
    ;

END
```

The above produces:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| OLD_VALUE_CODE | NEW_VALUE_CODE |
+----------------+----------------+
|     110.153.11 |  110.153.02.11 |
|     110.117.09 |  110.117.02.09 |
|     110.153.05 |  110.153.02.05 |
|     110.119.25 |  110.119.01.01 |
|     110.153.18 |  110.153.02.18 |
|     110.113.13 |  110.113.02.13 |
|     110.150.12 |  110.150.02.12 |
|     110.152.22 |  110.152.02.22 |
|     110.153.20 |  110.153.02.20 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    code
    ,CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(int,RIGHT(code,2)) BETWEEN 1 AND 24  THEN STUFF(code,8,0,'.02')
        WHEN CONVERT(int,RIGHT(code,2)) BETWEEN 25 AND 49  THEN LEFT(STUFF(code,8,0,'.01'),11)+LastSeq
        ELSE code
    ENd
from (
SELECT
    *

    ,LastSeq = right('00'+CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(int,RIGHT(code,2))-25+1),2)
FROM
    (
        values
            ('110.153.26')
            ,('110.153.25')
            ,('110.153.27')
            ,('110.153.11')
            ,('110.153.49')
    ) N(code)
) T
```

[image]